# VTK: display integration point data

Tags: vtk

I'm working with the VTK library in C++.

I have a mesh given as an unstructured grid and certain data given on integration points of gaussian quadrature on the cells (which was created by an external solver). For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that we talk about scalar data.

I also have a tool which displays VTK data graphically. What I want is to display the mentioned data with that tool, simply as interpolated/extrapolated scalar data on the whole grid.

My question is, is there something native to VTK with which I can give the mesh the scalar data at the integration points in some way and VTK handles the interpolation and extrapolation?

I mean, I could write an algorithm that processes the data, creates a new grid in which the cells do not share nodes (as the extrapolated values might not be continuous there), extrapolate the scalars to those nodes for each cell and then display that. However, by this I take away from the native possibilities of the VTK library (which seems to be quite strong in most other regards) and I don't want to reinvent the wheel anyway.

From https://vtk.org/Wiki/images/7/78/VTK-Quadrature-Point-Design-Doc.pdf, I am aware that there is the `vtkQuadratureSchemeDefinition` class and I think I know how to handle it, and I noticed `vtkQuadraturePointInterpolator`, which seems to do the opposite of what I'm searching for - interpolation to the integration points rather than extrapolating from them.

The newest entry in the VTK wiki otherwise seems to be https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_integration_point_support, which seems to be quite old, given that it pleads for the existence of some sort of quadrature point support in general, which currently already exists.

Also there is a question in the VTK mailing list which looks just like my question here:
https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtkusers/2013-January/078077.html, which seems to be without an answer.

Likewise, the issue https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues/17124 also seems to be about what I want to do, and it might hint at it currently not being possible, but it existing as an issue does not imply that it is not already solved (especially with no asignee to the issue).